# Show all values in Chart js y axis

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have following chart:
[Chart](https://jsfiddle.net/62uak2t3/2/)

I want letters in my y-axis so I have added a switch in my chart options for triggering the appropriate letter for a y axis value. My problem is that the y axis shows only even values thus returning in the half of the switch values(xc,B,A+, etc...). But I want to show all the values in y axis, 0 to 13. Is there any method of achieving this? Help is really appreciated.

```js
var data = {
  labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
  datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    fill: false,
    lineTension: 0,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
    borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    borderCapStyle: 'butt',
    borderDash: [],
    borderDashOffset: 0.0,
    borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
    pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
    pointBorderWidth: 2,
    pointHoverRadius: 5,
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
    pointRadius: 1,
    pointHitRadius: 10,
    data: [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
  }]
};

var options = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        // Create scientific notation labels
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          switch (value) {
            case 0:
              return 'XC';
            case 1:
              return 'C';
            case 2:
              return 'B';
            case 3:
              return 'A';
            case 4:
              return 'A+';
            case 5:
              return 'BA';
            case 6:
              return 'N+';
            case 7:
              return 'C-';
            case 8:
              return 'D+';
            case 9:
              return 'D';
            case 10:
              return 'D-';
            case 11:
              return 'N';
            case 12:
              return 'N-';
            case 13:
              return 'NR';
            default:
              return '';
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    }]
  }
};

var ctx = $('#chart');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi chartjs allowing the yaxis values visible upto 10  data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7 , 8 , 9, 10], if u increase more its auto adjusting

Comment: @gayathri : ok but can you give me a work around for that?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2801) helps someone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the ticks object you can also supply `min`, `max` and `stepSize` to override the default auto adjust behaviour

(more information can ben seen in the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-linear-scale) on all available properties)

```
ticks: {
    min: 0,
    max: 13,
    stepSize: 1,
    ........REST OF THE OBJECT.....
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/jnej9vez/)

Comment: to be found here http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html?h=ticks%3A%20%7B 
really not intuitive to notice ..

Answer (score 0):

If anyone will have similiar problem, but with steps that are not bigger by 1 from each other (or other numbers which have common divisor) what means that solution above would not work - here's my solution.
Just return all ticks in "afterBuildTicks" callback in chart.option.scales.yAxes

```
  chart.options.scales = {
  yAxes: [{
    ticks,
    afterBuildTicks: (scale, yTicks) => yourTicks
  }]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for a solution, the `autoSkip` option should be set to `false`, and the graph won't make any adjustments if the ticks don't fit.

See https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html?h=ticks%3A%20%7B#common-tick-options-to-all-cartesian-axes